# Is there a standard lightning solution to email all contacts from a case?

Tags: lightning, email, case, contact, standard-objects

What is the Lighting standard solution to email all or selected contacts from the **contact roles** list on a case?

In classic, the contact roles list has a standard **send an email** button.

[image]

When pressed, it populates the cc: box with email addresses from all contacts in the list.

[image]

However in Lightning, no send an email feature button exists on the contact roles list.

[image]

And only the primary contact's email populates when composing an email.

[image]

It would seem a pretty basic need for a case user to want to email all contacts from the list, but I can't see how it's done.

What am I missing? I can think a of a few ways to code such a thing, but it seems such basic functionality that I hesitate to build anything.

I can't find anyone talking about this issue, so think maybe a feature in this org is disabled or something else? How do you email every contact on a case in Lightning?

Thanks much for any insight.